# Does FluentNHibernate Support SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I know they support SQL CE.  I think they go up to 3.5???  I just downloaded CE 4.0 and I wanted to test it out in my project but I can't get it configured right in FluentNHibernate...

**If 4.0 is supported**:

What version do I have to download and could someone give me an example of how to implement it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FNH supports CE 4.0, try this configuration:

```
var config = Fluently.Configure()
 .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString("Data Source=DatabaseFileName.sdf"))
 .Mappings(m =>
 {
     m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(typeof(Entity).Assembly);
 })
 .BuildConfiguration();
```

Assemblies with your entity mappings should be added via AddFromAssembly. DatabaseFileName.sdf is path and file name of the database file name. Path can be or absolute or relative to working directory of the application (windows application: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; web application: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath).

Tested on FNH1.0, NH2.1 and [SQL Server CE 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2).

EDIT:
The database file must be created by the database engine:

```
using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString))
{
    engine.CreateDatabase();
}
```

Here is an example for CE 3.5 but it should work with CE 4.0 as well: http://nhdatabasescopes.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f9e824a457e8#DatabaseScopes%2fMsSqlCeInFilePrivateScope.cs.

Comment: Did you test this using Compact Edition **4.0**?

Comment: In the example explained above, where is the "DatabaseFileName.sdf" physically stored at in your file system?  Where did you place you DLLs for SQL Server CE?

Comment: Yes, it works fine with CE 4.0. My project references assembly that is placed in program files folder (something like this c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\) - most likely not the optimal way for XCOPY deployment. Copy Local must be set to true for the assembly. The database file is created in base directory of your process - System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory (windows application) or System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath (web application).

Comment: Ok! Does FluentNHibernate automatically create the *.sdf file for you when you set it up to Fluently.Configure()?

Comment: It is like exam in a school:). Database engine has to create the file.

Comment: Now if only there were a way to edit a DB in Compact Edition 4.0 through some kind of User Interface...